# Query only opportunities with tasks in apex

Tags: salesforce, apex, soql

I'm trying to query only opportunities that have tasks associated with the following query:

```
Select Id, (id, status from tasks) from opportunity where id in (select whatid from task)
```

The where condition is not compiling, any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

"Task is not supported for semi-join inner SELECTs"

You're welcome to upvote an idea, it's only 7 years old ;) https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000J68oAAC

You can't do a rollup summary of activities either, to put a counter of Tasks for example. Messy...

- you can just ignore it, SELECT all opps and filter them manually in Apex `if(!opp.Tasks.isEmpty()){/*do my stuff */}`
- You can try splitting it into 2 queries, get a `Set<Id>` of `Task.WhatId` and then bind that to second, Opp-related query...
- you can put some helper field on Opp that would help you identify them (and in future populate it with a cross-object workflow? process builder? Task trigger?)
- you can consider using a report with "Opportunities with Tasks" cross filter and then fetch that report's results with Analytics REST API. That counts as a callout though and it's limited to 2K rows I think.